# When I turn my monitor on after it has been off, it does not display anything

Tags: xubuntu, xorg, display, lightdm

I am running Xubuntu 14.10 on a desktop and use LightDM. As I said in the title after I turn off my monitor (with the computer already on) and then turn it back on again there is no input from my computer. I can get the display to show again by blindly typing <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> to get a terminal and then `xrandr --auto`. Also, it can also be solved by `sudo restart lightdm` after going to `tty1`, but this resets the session.

However, if I had locked the computer with light-locker prior to turning off the monitor, the background on the greeter is just changed to the default and I can login.

The monitor is connected via HDMI, and I am using Intel integrated graphics. Is there any way to prevent this problem?

Comment: Are you looking for an absolute solution or a workaround?

Comment: I am looking for an absolute solution or a permanent workaround, since doing one of the temporary workarounds I mentioned each time is annoying.